# User Authorization with Djoser, DRF and Pinia

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pinia, djoser, nuxt3

I've been facing difficulties with authorization for several days now. While my authentication appears to be functioning properly, I haven't been able to successfully implement posting data to my backend that uses DRF and Djoser. I think the issue is minor and I'm using Pinia, Nuxt3, Django, and DRF.

my settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'djoser',
    'corsheaders',

    'blog',
    'users',
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]
```

my main urls

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from . import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    path('user/', include('users.urls', namespace='user')),
]
```

and user urls

```
from django.urls import path, include

from .views import CustomUserViewSet

app_name = 'user'

urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
    path('custom/', CustomUserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='custom-list'),
    path('custom/<int:pk>/', CustomUserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}),                  name='custom-detail'),
]
```

and my views

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework import generics, status, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Category, Comment, Post
from .serializers import PostSerializer, CommentSerializer, CategorySerializer

User = get_user_model()


class PostListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    lookup_field = "slug"
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

on the Front end Nuxts and pinia

my pinia stores:
auth.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useAuthStore = defineStore({
  id: 'user',
  state: () => ({
    user: {
      isAuthenticated: true,
      username: null,
      token: null,
    },
    errors: []
  }),
  actions: {
    initStore() {
      this.user.isAuthenticated = false

      if (localStorage.getItem('user.token')) {
        this.user.token = localStorage.getItem('user.token')
        this.user.username = localStorage.getItem('user.username')
        this.user.isAuthenticated = true

        console.log('Initalized user is:', this.user, this.token)
      }
    },
    setToken(token, username) {
      console.log('setToken', token, username)

      this.user.token = token
      this.user.username = username
      this.user.isAuthenticated = true

      localStorage.setItem('user.token', token)
      localStorage.setItem('user.username', username)
    },
    async loginUser(email, password) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/auth/token/login', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: email,
            password: password
          })
        })

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials')
        }
        const data = await response.json()
        this.setToken(data.auth_token, email)

        return true
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)

        this.errors.push('Invalid credentials')

        return false
      }
    }
  },
})
```

posts.js

```
import {defineStore} from 'pinia';
import {useAuthStore} from '@/stores/auth';

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8000';

export const usePostStore = defineStore({
    id: 'post',
    state: () => ({
        posts: [],
        post: null,
        loading: false,
        error: null,
        categories: [],
        slug: null,
    }),
    actions: {
        async addPost(post) {
            try {
                const authStore = useAuthStore();
                const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/blog/`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        // 'Authorization': 'token ' + authStore.user.token,
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(post),
                });
                const data = await response.json();
                this.posts.push(data);
            } catch (error) {
                this.error = error.message;
            }
        },
        async fetchPosts() {
            this.loading = true
            try {
                const authStore = useAuthStore();
                const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/blog/`, {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Authorization': `token ${authStore.user.token}`,
                        }
                    }
                )
                const data = await response.json();
                this.posts = data
            } catch (error) {
                this.error = error.message;
            } finally {
                this.loading = false
            }
        },

    }
});
```

my nuxt
app.vue

```
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage/>
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useAuthStore } from '@/stores/auth'

const userStore = useAuthStore()

onMounted(() => {
  userStore.initStore()
})
</script>
posts.vue
<template>
  <div><div><BlogForm/></div>
    <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
    <div v-else-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
    <div v-else>
      <h1>Posts</h1>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="post in posts" :key="post.slug">
          <NuxtLink :to="`/posts/${post.slug}`">{{ post.title }}</NuxtLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { usePostStore } from '@/stores/posts'

const postStore = usePostStore()
const { posts, loading, error } = storeToRefs(postStore)
const { fetchPosts } = postStore

fetchPosts()
</script>
```

and my components
blogForm.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Add Post</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input id="title" v-model="title" />
      <label for="content">Content</label>
      <input id="content" v-model="content" />
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

  <script setup>
  
  import { usePostStore } from '@/stores/posts'
  import slugify from 'slugify'
  
  const postStore = usePostStore()
  
  const title = ref('')
  const content = ref('')
  
  const submit = () => {
    const slug = slugify(title.value, {
      lower: true,
      strict: true,
    })
    postStore.addPost ({
      title: title.value,
      slug,
      content:content.value,
    })
    title.value = ''
    content.value = ''
  }
  </script>
```

the Error
GET http://localhost:8000/blog/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
POST http://localhost:8000/blog/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED